# Prove that $\emptyset^*=\{\epsilon\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages

I want to prove that $\emptyset^*=\{\epsilon\}$. I would start by the definition of Kleene star:
$$\emptyset^*=\bigcup^\infty_{i=0}\emptyset^i=\emptyset^0+\emptyset^1+...$$
and since $A^0=\{\epsilon\}$ for any set $A$, we have $\emptyset^0=\{\epsilon\}$. Other powers give $\emptyset$ (because $\emptyset \ \cap \ \emptyset=\emptyset$). So the sum is $\{\epsilon\}=\emptyset^*$.
Is this correct?

Comment: It's spelled Kleene, not Klenee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that $\emptyset^n=\emptyset$ for $n\geq1$, but I don't see why that would follow from $\emptyset\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$. Do you mean concatenation there, rather than intersection? Either way I would explain more about how you come to that conclusion.

Comment: Oh, okay, I didn't know that $\emptyset^n=\{\epsilon\}$. So what we have here is $\bigcup^\infty_{i=0}\epsilon$, but does it immediately follow that $\bigcup^\infty_{i=0}\epsilon=\epsilon$?

Comment: No, sorry! $\emptyset^n=\emptyset$ like you said, since there are no strings to use to concatenate. Saying the powers are $\{\epsilon\}$ is incorrect. I will edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Okay, I think now I get everything ;) Thank you